401 errors when trying to restore dotnet program in Rider on Linux
I had a dotnet program that was working fine. I pulled the latest master on JetBrain Rider 2024.2.4. I am suddenly getting NU1301
Troubleshooting I've done:

Dotnet clean && dotnet restore
re-cloning from main
dotnet restore --interactive
refreshed my Gitlab PAT
deleted and recreated my feeds
added my PAT and username manually in the .config file
List item

<packageSourceCredentials>
     <gitlab>
       <add key="Username" value="naername" />
       <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="pat" />
     </gitlab>
   </packageSourceCredentials>

I apologize if this has already been asked, I searched the forums here and tried all the resolutions but I'm losing my mind and I have a minor C# Bug fix need to push out tomorrow.

Please try setting Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | NuGet | Credential Provider to NuGet/.NET CLI plugins.
If that doesn't help, please create a new support ticket (Help | Contact Support) with the following logs:

Enable NuGet All, NuGetSearch trace scenarios via Help | Diagnostic
Tools | Choose Trace Scenarios;
Reproduce the issue;
Share the output in the NuGet tool window | Log tab;
Collect logs via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data;
Disable the trace scenarios enabled previosly;

